# Perl: What does this "=~s|" mean in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to Perl regex. I am trying to understand a chunk of existing code that parses a file and modifies it based on certain groups of comments.

The code has the following lines:

```
sub parse_comments{
    #.... function to parse and modify comments
    ....
}

open(FILEP, $filename);
$filecontent = join('', <FILEP>); #load the whole file(s) in one string
close(FILEP);

$filecontent =~s|[\x0b\x0c]+|&parse_comments($&)|gxe;
$filecontent =~s/[#][^\n]*/&parse_comments($&)/gxe;
```

I understand that the "s/" in line# 5 stands for substitution. Zero or more occurrences of '#' and '^\n' are substituted in the function "parse_comments".

But I am not clear on what line# 4 does. I understand that "|" is the alternation operator. But what does "=~s|" accomplish here ? What does the "s" stand for ?

Comment: `|` here is not an operator, but a delimiter. `s/FOO/BAR/` can be written with alternative delimiters instead of a slash. For example `s@FOO@BAR@`, `s|FOO|BAR|` or `s{FOO}{BAR}`. They all mean the same thing. Choosing an alternative delimiter is often a good choice if your regular expression contains slashes for example.

Comment: There does not seem to be any need to change delimiter there, unless that function inserts slashes in the string. I have some doubts as to whether `e` eval modifier is really needed. It is a potential security risk, as people can insert arbitrary code there and have it executed. We can see that the author of the code is using `x` modifier needlessly. Probably a matter of string interpolation, one can hope, and there are better ways to deal with that.

Comment: Also, it is `=~ s|`. But Perl allows you to skip some spaces. Not a recommended practice, especially if you are changing delimiters. And it makes the code less readable.